# my mysql doesn't working where am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the data from my database according to the certain id if the database.

Here is my code. But they are not working else 
`$selectquery,$resultsgetdata,$countprodu`

```
<?php
$profrom = $_GET['id'];
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = '$profrom'";
$resultsgetdata = mysql_query($selectquery);
$countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);
if($countprodu>0)
{
$proidid = $row['proid'];
$proidName = $row['proName'];
$proidDescription = $row['proDescription'];
$Category   = $row['proCategory'];
$Price    = $row['Price'];
$Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];
}

echo $proidid;
?>
```

Comment: $selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = ".$profrom, with your current query string your using proid = $profrom instead of proid = "actual id" (ex. 1)

Comment: Please format your code. This is extremely difficult to read, and it's not even clear what you're asking. "Not working" how?

Comment: i hope now its ok?

Comment: i didnt get you @Dr.Stitch

Comment: You forget to fetch data from your query result. Use `mysql_fetch_array()` for this . Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use `mysqli or pdo`

Comment: can you please help me to get a good understanding about this fetching ? or can you please write a example query ?

Comment: @LeoneMaleash, try this change first -> $selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = ".$profrom

Comment: please check @jothi's comment

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your forgot to  fetch the value try this

```js
<?php
$profrom = $_GET['id'];
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = '$profrom'";
$resultsgetdata = mysql_query($selectquery);
$countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);
if($countprodu>0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsgetdata){

$proidid = $row['proid'];
$proidName = $row['proName'];
$proidDescription = $row['proDescription'];
$Category   = $row['proCategory'];
$Price    = $row['Price'];
$Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];
}

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

```
<?php
$profrom = $_GET['id'];
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = '$profrom'";
$resultsgetdata = mysql_query($selectquery);
$countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);
if($countprodu>0)
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsgetdata))
  {
    $proidid = $row['proid']; 
    $proidName = $row['proName'];
    $proidDescription = $row['proDescription'];
    $Category   = $row['proCategory'];
    $Price    = $row['Price'];
    $Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];

    echo $proidid;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try this its useful to your criteria. @Leone Maleash

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will work,

```
<?php
$profrom = $_GET['id'];
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE proid = '$profrom'";
$resultsgetdata = mysql_query($selectquery);
$countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);
if($countprodu>0)
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultsgetdata))
  {
    $proidid = $row['proid']; 
    $proidName = $row['proName'];
    $proidDescription = $row['proDescription'];
    $Category   = $row['proCategory'];
    $Price    = $row['Price'];
    $Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];

    echo $proidid;
  }
}
?>
```